# Getting reindexing issue after 2.4.1 to 2.4.5 commerce upgrade

Tags: upgrade, commerce

$ bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_flat
Product Flat Data index process error during indexation process:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'row_id' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tmp_indexer` (`row_id`, `entity_id`, `type_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `created_at`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `sku`, `updated_at`) SELECT `e`.`row_id`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`updated_at` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (e.created_in <= '1655131200') AND (e.updated_in > '1655131200')

In the database, I don't have a table. Tries Multiple solutions not working.